# How to render a r-chunk code as verbatim in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Consider the following `rmarkdown` document:

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  sec1: 1
---

```{r echo = FALSE}
sec1_is_0 <- params$sec1 == 0
sec1_is_1 <- params$sec1 == 1
```
    
## section 1

```{r a, echo = sec1_is_0, eval = FALSE}
x <- 2
y <- 3

x+y
```
    
```{r b, echo = sec1_is_1, eval = FALSE}
x <- 4
y <- 5

x+y
```
  
### A

```{r a, echo = FALSE, eval = sec1_is_0, results='hide'}
```

```{r b, echo = FALSE, eval = sec1_is_1, results='hide'}
```

`r round(x+y, 3)`

### B

```{r b, echo = FALSE, eval = sec1_is_0, results='hide'}
```

```{r a, echo = FALSE, eval = sec1_is_1, results='hide'}
```

`r round(x+y, 3)`
````

How can we get this document rendered as a `markdown` file (notice `markdown` and not `rmarkdown`) such that the `r-chunks` converted to `verbatim`:

```
## section 1

\begin{verbatim}
x <- 4
y <- 5

x+y
\end{verbatim}

### A

9

### B

5
```

Comment: does simply changing `output: pdf_document` to `output: md_document` not do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, @wurli: Unfortunately, `output: md_document` does not do the trick.

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `output: md_document` instead of `output: pdf_document` in the yaml frontmatter. This gives the following output:

```
## section 1

    x <- 4
    y <- 5

    x+y

### A

9

### B

5
```

Note that the indented lines are equivalent to using `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I wrote before, as an answer to your comment, it does not work, @wurli, for my purposes: I will need to process further the `md` file and, therefore, I do need to have `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.